# How to pass jquery variable data in php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i having that script from this script i got one id in following text box but i want that in php variable to pass this query
"$sub_desti_id" is available in that text box i using this on pop up box to fetch the data  thats why i dont want to submit the page .please help me in this case

```
$small_hotel="SELECT * FROM small_add WHERE sub_dest='$sub_desti_id' ";


<input type="hidden" id="bookId" name="bookId" >

 <script>
        $(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
         var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
         $(".modal-body #bookId").val( myBookId );
        $('#small_add').modal('show');
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: to pass var from js to php, need to make an ajax or any other complex method. Not the same when you pass from php to js

Comment: i tried ajax but not working in that

Comment: @Vivak "*i tried ajax but not working in that*" - What did you try? Can you please show us your code?

Comment: <script>
  $(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
   var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
   $(".modal-body #bookId").val( myBookId );
  $('#small_add').modal('show');
   $.post('a.php', 'val=' + $(this).data('id'), function (response) {
      alert(response);
   });
  });
  </script>                                                                                                       <?php
   $value = $_POST['val'];
   echo $value;
?>

Comment: Please add the code in the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass variables between PHP and JQuery.
But you can try something like this, it's not the best, but can set you on the right way. Get your data using PHP and place it in a DOM element like an input or div. Then access this DOM Element using Jquery

```
// Variable tha recieve the data
<?php $var = "Data"; ?>

// Placing the data in DOM
<input type='text' id='data' value='<?php echo $var ?>'>

// Retrieving using JQuery
<script>
    var data = document.getElementById('data').value;
    alert(data);
</script>
```

Comment: Of course you can also set it to a variable by directly printing it inside `<script>` tag. `<script> var data = '<?php echo $var ?>';</script>`